# Cant edit Configure Service Application Associations

Tags: proxy

Can you please help me with this issue, for some reason I cant tick the box for Search Service Application Proxy on service connections. Its greyed out.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

At the top edit the following group of connections now it is shown as "**Default**" change to **Custom** from that dropdown list. Now you can select all checkbox whichever you need.

Please see the below, with the **default** mode, service application is disabled, we cannot select the checkbox - now it is in disabled mode, even we cannot uncheck the selection.

[image: service application selection is disabled with default mode]

With the **Custom** mode, service application is enabled, we can select any checkbox:

[image: service application selection is enabled in custom mode]